# Change background image with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery to change specific elements background image. I got it working, but if i put same named element, it duplicates background from another element and doesn't take photo from itself. And no, I cannot change class names, they must be the same.

JS:

```
$(".tumblr-photoset").each(function() {
  $(".photo-slideshow").css("background-image", "url(" + $('.photo-slideshow img:first-child').attr('src') + ")");
});
```

CODEPEN:

http://codepen.io/aleksitappura/pen/xshvy

So the code takes first photo of `.photoset` and changes background image with it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell it to look for the first photo inside its children elements, not the whole set:

```
$(".tumblr-photoset").each(function() {
    $(this).find(".photo-slideshow").css(
        "background-image", 
        "url(" + $(this).find('.photo-slideshow img:first-child').attr('src') + ")"
    );
});
```

So, `$(this).find(".photo-slideshow")` is the key, `$(this)` being the currently iterated object.

See here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hnJwp

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you need the each statement.

Is this sort of what you are after?

```
$(".photo-slideshow").css("background-image", "url(" + $(this, 'img:first-child').attr('src') + ")");
```

You need to search in the scope of the `.photo-slideshow`

The output returns: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jauir